# How to inheritance superClass when the superclass is a generic class in Swift

Tags: swift, inheritance, generic-programming

I have two questions need to be solved .

the first Question :

A Superclass , the name is FatherClass , a subclass inheritance the super class ,
please read this code :

```
class FatherClass <FT> {
}

class SubClass : FatherClass { // Error : Reference to generic type 'MyFatherClass' requires arguments in <...>
}
```

How to solve it  ? please help me , thanks .

[image]

### ---------------------------

the second Question:

please read this code :

```
class FatherClass <FT>{
    FT fatheType ; // Error : Expected declaration
}
```

FT is a generic type ,

Why the property fatherType have error ? what's Expected declaration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
class SubClass<FT> : FatherClass<FT> { 
}

or a specific type of FatherClass

class SubClass : FatherClass<String> {
}

or 

class SubClass<ST> : FatherClass<Int> {
}
```

Comment: Thank you for solve the problem first ， but the second problem , can you help me ?

Comment: Try this. `var fatherType:FT`